# continue click action after preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to format existing href attribute based on click event. Below is mys code.

```
var clicked = false;
$('a').click(function(e) {
if(clicked === true){
//link already formatted
// link should open here
}
else{
 e.preventDefault();
//code to format link
clicked = true;
$(this).trigger('click');
}
});
```

Now the issue is, I am able to format the link and then trigger click event; but link is not opening.

Kindly help/guide.

Note : question/query is more towards triggering the click event with modified link.. this part is not explained/answered in any existing threads.

Comment: Show your markup and what you actually doing to format please.

Comment: below is code in else logic..

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara. The accepted answer from the question you marked as duplicate uses the same technique as OP. I think the problem is not in _how to trigger the click event in an anchor_

Comment: @Guedes The key part of the accepted answer: *"Beware though, that even in the event gets fired, the browser will not follow the link href."* That's why *"link is not opening"*.

Comment: below is code to format href... else{
     e.preventDefault();
    //code to format link
 var pathName = location.pathname;
 var target = $(this).attr("href") + "?source=" + pathName ;
 $(this).attr('href',target);
 console.log($(this).attr("href"));
 console.log("prevent default");
    clicked = true;
    $(this).trigger('click');
    }

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara. Does it mean that `.trigger('click')` is an untrusted event? Or something like that? Anyways, how does this solves OP problem?

Comment: @Guedes Yes, it's untrusted when manually triggered. #2 answer suggests using `window.open` instead.

Comment: Hm ok... @Jacke. Try `location.href = this.href;` instead of `$(this).trigger('click');`

Comment: @Guedes- thanks a lot, that worked..but its not working for #link.